# Spin, isospin, parity etc. in nuclear physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, parity

I have one question regarding these quantum numbers. When I read through my textbook, it sometimes just says something like: "And this atoms ground state has $J^{\pi} = 0^+$ and isospin $+1$" - as an example.

Is this supposed to be measured quantities, that you just look up (I know you can do that), or is there some trick to see that, oh, that atom got this and that.

It has just been bothering me :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're specifically asking for atoms, not elementary particles, right?

Comment: Ultimately everything in physics has to be a measured quantitatively... but the trick is to bring order into the chaos of these measurements. Determining the absolute energy levels in atoms beyond hydrogen theoretically is a very tough business, because the inner electrons for large Z are relativistic and the couplings are very strong. However, determining the electronic structure and the selection rules that lead to singlet/multiplet lines, shifts in electric and magnetic fields etc. can be done by means of symmetries that are effectively described by these conserved quantum numbers.

Comment: Because you're asking about isospin of atoms, I assume you're  referring to the atomic nucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground state nuclear spin quantum number and parity, $J^{\pi}$ for all even-even nuclei is $0^+$. The isospin can vary, but for the ground state of even-even will *probably* be either 0 or 1.

The isospin quantum number, $I$, is limited to the range of $$\frac{|Z-N|}{2}\le I \le \frac{Z+N}{2}.$$

The $J$ for odd-mass-number nuclei will be a half-integer (1/2, 3/2, 5/2, etc.) and the parity depends on the *shell* of the extra (odd) nucleon.

The $J$ of odd-Z/odd-N nuclei are integer, but not necessarily zero, and the parity, depends on a combination of *shells* which contain the odd nucleons.

See [this Wikipedia article to learn about the nuclear shell model.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model)

Comment: It's maybe helpful to add that $J$ is a good quantum number, parity is almost good (broken by the weak interaction), and isospin is slightly less good (broken by electromagnetic and strong nuclear interactions). So that saying a state has a certain isospin is an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The quantum numbers are "parameters" that characterize the states of a particle or an atom. If I understand correctly what is your question, it is not always possible to measure directly all the quantum numbers, but sometimes you have to use some tricks to calculate them (for example special experiments or calculations based on the properties of the quantum number that you are considering).